# Reading and writing to a text file

Tags: vb.net

I need to store the scores for two players in a text file. I need to then simulate throwing dice, carrying out a calculation on the result of the dice throw and amend the scores for the players in the text file. so far to create the text file i have the code below. Any help on how to update the scores after rolling the dice would be very appreciated.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim filepath As String = "H:\SomeFileName.txt"
        If Not System.IO.File.Exists(filepath) Then
            System.IO.File.Create(filepath).Dispose()
        End If

        Dim ObjFso
        Dim StrFileName
        Dim ObjFile
        StrFileName = "H:\SomeFileName.txt"
        ObjFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        'Creating a file for writing data
        ObjFile = ObjFso.CreateTextFile(StrFileName)
        'Writing a string into the file
        ObjFile.WriteLine("Player 1")
        ObjFile.WriteLine("Player 2.")
        'Closing the file
        ObjFile.Close()


    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

That's VBA way to write file, in VB.NET use [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx) object (You have tagged this question as VB.NET, right?)

```
    Dim filepath As String = "H:\SomeFileName.txt"
    Using sw = new StreamWriter(filepath , false)
       sw.WriteLine("Player 1")
       sw.WriteLine("Player 2.")
    End Using
```

StreamWriter creates the file if it doesn't exists and overwrites or appends to the content inside the file depending on the last `Append` flag